# Pass parameter to p:remoteCommand to backing bean method and get result before page submit

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

in my requirement i have 4 text filed Quantity,Rate In,Tax Rate,Total Amount 
    values enter in quantity,rate in tax rate after some calculate it should display in Grand Total it is working fine but now this Grand Total i need to pass to managed bean method and before submit it should display the result in Grand Total filed

[reference page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLPvb.png)
here's my xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 


<h:head>
    <title>ACIM</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/global.css" />

    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript target="head"> 
 $ = jQuery;
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").keyup(function(){
          var val1 = +$("#myForm\\:quantit").val();
          var val2 = +$("#myForm\\:rte").val();
          $("#myForm\\:total_Amount").val(val1*val2);
         var val3 = +$("#myForm\\:total_Amount").val();           
          var val4 = $("#myForm\\:tax").val();
           $("#myForm\\:grand_Total").val(val3*val4/100);
           command([{name:'param',value:val3}]);           
     }); 
});
</h:outputScript>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form>
        <div id="header">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h1 id="logo">
                    <img src="../images/worldofficelogo-white.png" alt="image"
                        class="logo" />
                </h1>
                <h2 class="slogan">                 
                </h2>
            </h:panelGrid>          
        </div>
        <div id="tabs">
            <div id="tabs">
                <ul class="box">

                    <li><a href="accountsHome.xhtml">Expense</a></li>
                    <li id="active"><a href="accountspurchaseorder.xhtml">Purchase
                            Order</a></li>
                    <li><a href="accountspurchaseentry.xhtml">Purchase Entry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Invoice</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="SalesInvoice.xhtml">Sales Invoice</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ServiceInvoice.xhtml">Service Invoice</a></li>
                        </ul></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="myForm">
        <div class="msg">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%">
                <h2>Welcome to Your P.O Management</h2>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </div><br/><br/>
        <hr style="margin-top: 24px;" />
        <div id="page" class="box">
            <p:messages for="login" showDetail="true" closable="true"
                style="text-align:center"></p:messages>
            <div class="content" style="margin-left: 200px">
                <h:panelGrid columns="6" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">                   

                    <h:outputText value="Quantity"></h:outputText>
                    <h:inputText class="input" id="quantit"
                        value="#{purchaseOrderBean.quantity}">                      
                    </h:inputText>                  


                    <h:outputText value="Rate In"></h:outputText>
                    <h:inputText class="input" id="rte"
                        value="#{purchaseOrderBean.rate}" required="true">                      
                    </h:inputText>

                    <h:outputText value="Tax Rate" class="left1"></h:outputText>
                    <h:inputText class="input" id="tax" value="#{purchaseOrderBean.taxRate}" required="true">                       
                    </h:inputText>                  

                </h:panelGrid>
                <br /><br />
                <h:outputText value="Total Amount" class="total"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText class="input" style="border:none;margin-left:25px"
                    readonly="true" id="total_Amount"
                    value="#{purchaseOrderBean.totalAmount}">
                </h:inputText>
                <br /> <br /> <br />

                <h:outputText value="Grand Total" class="total"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText class="input" style="border:none;margin-left:25px"
                    readonly="true" id="grand_Total"
                    value="#{purchaseOrderBean.grandTotal}">
                    <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="rs"
                        currencyCode="INR" locale="en" />
                </h:inputText>
                <br /> <br /> <br />

                <h:outputText value="Grand Total Amount In Words" class="total"></h:outputText>
                <p:remoteCommand name="command" actionListener="#{purchaseOrderBean.getjs()}" />


                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-left:500px;">
                    <h:commandButton class="button" value="save"
                        action="#{purchaseOrderBean.save()}"></h:commandButton>
                    <h:commandButton class="button" value="Cancel" type="reset"></h:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

here's my managed bean method:

```
 public void getjs(){
              FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
              Map<String, String> map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
              String value = (String) map.get("param");
              System.out.println("**************** ***************** " + value);
            }
```

till  $("#myForm\:grand_Total").val(val3*val4/100); in my xhtml page working but  command([{name:'param',value:val3}]); not working
the problem how to pass values to managed bean  p:remoteCommand  the getjs method not getting values of param  please suggest me a way to do this